# Speaker recognition in Python 2.7 and Windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I would like to know if there is any algorithm or library that will help me build a program that will help me to detect only my voice and everything I say, I am using the speech recognition library with python 2.7. Please I need help. I'm beginner using Python

Comment: _Voice recognition_ is a generic term that doesn't tell exactly what you want to achieve. When you say _voice recognition_ most people will understand _speech recognition_ (as @DavidGay did), but what you are after is "speaker recognition".

Comment: Exactly that topic was what I was looking for, but for language issues and confusion with voice recognition I have not found anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

The `pocketsphinx` library may be what you're looking for: https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx

There are Python bindings here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pocketsphinx

Comment: I'm looking for something that keeps my voice in audio files and then from those files this program detect my voice, a library that handles the speaker recognition.